# Роковини і річниця

Tags: синоніми

Останнім часом часто стикаюся з тим, що уникають вживання виразу "річниця смерті", а саме для згадування дати смерті вживають "роковини". Хоча Словник Української мови подає практично однакові плумачння цих слів.
[роковини](http://sum.in.ua/s/rokovyny)
[річниця](http://sum.in.ua/s/richnycja)

Чи має зміст саме так застосовувати ці слова?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Справді, **СУМ-11** подає однакове визначення [*річниці*](http://sum.in.ua/s/richnycja) та [*роковин*](http://sum.in.ua/s/rokovyny):

> Календарна дата, коли закінчується ще один рік від початку якої-небудь події.

Окремо зазначено, що *роковини* - це:

> День народження, іменини.

**Борис Рогоза** в "Уроках державної мови" цитує СУМ-11 та [зауважує](http://mova.kreschatic.kiev.ua/64.htm), що *роковини* - це також *день смерті*, хоч і в тлумачних словниках це значення окремо не виділяється. Автор рубрики зазначає, що *річниця* - це те ж, що і *роковини*.

**Проф. Пономарів** також [вважає](https://www.bbc.com/ukrainian/blogs/2014/10/141014_ponomariv_blog32_ko) ці слова синонімами:

> Календарна дата, коли закінчується ще один рік від початку якоїсь події, в українській мові має два лексичні позначення: *роковини* й *річниця*. У слова *роковини* давніша традиція вживання в українській мові. [...] Слово *річниця* з'явилося пізніше.

Як синоніми ці слова подає [сайт](http://lcorp.ulif.org.ua/dictua/) "Словники України" on-line:

> **РІЧНИ́ЦЯ** (календарна дата, коли закінчується рік від якоїсь події); **РОКОВИ́НИ**, **ЮВІЛЕ́Й** (така дата, перев. обчислювана десятиріччями, століттями тощо).

Вживання саме слова *роковини* щодо чиєїсь смерті, мабуть, пов'язане з церковним значенням цього слова. Так, за **Словником церковно-обрядової термінології**, *[роковини](http://slovopedia.org.ua/43/53408/295051.html)* - це:

> 1. Заупокійне богослужіння в річницю смерті;
> 2. Поминальний день - річниця смерті.

В мережі [можна знайти](https://chas.cv.ua/ukrnet/31246-rchnicya-chi-rokovini.html) приклади протиставлення *річниці* і *роковин* як чогось позитивного та негативного:

> Інакше наші нащадки не будуть святкувати чергові річниці Революції Гідності, а із сумом згадуватимуть її роковини.

Інший приклад - [тут](https://zik.ua/news/2015/06/02/richnytsya_chy_rokovyny_594976).

---

Тобто словники та мовознавці, зазвичай, не розрізняють слів *роковини* та *річниця* і вважають їх синонімами. Обидва слова можуть означати ще один рік після якоїсь події, в тому числі дня народження чи дня смерті.

Однак у певному контексті слово *роковини* може означати саме річницю смерті чи якоїсь сумної події. Водночас, сказати *річниця смерті* замість *роковин* не буде помилкою.